# Huge power drain since I switched from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, battery, powertop

I have just recently installed Linux aside from Windows on my Huawei Matebook X Pro, but faced significantly less battery life than on Windows. When I switch to Windows I get around 10 hours while Linux only runs for 2 hours on battery. That's an 80% drop! I tried out many things but wasn't successful. The battery reports a discharge rate of 24 W/h.

Version of the Matebook:

Intel® Core™ i5-8250U processor
NVIDIA® GeForce® MX150 with 2 GB GDDR5

Powertop Screens:

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku5ij.png)

[Device stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Yx2.png)

Comment: See some possible solutions in [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/55185/how-to-maximize-the-battery-life-on-your-linux-laptop/). Pay special attention to the advice regarding NVIDIA Optimus, since Linux will use the NVIDIA graphics all the time by default.

Comment: What does `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` say? If it says `performance` it means you're not using power saving functionality and running your CPU always at maximum frequency. That could be part of the problem. You might want to install a power manager software or set the scaling governor to something else, like `powersave`. [More info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling).

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

@harrymc: I've already adjusted my graphics drivers.     

Marco Bonelli: It's already set to powersave. CPU frequency is at 799 MHz.

Comment: Try to disable NVIDIA and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @harrymc: at the end it was actually the NVIDIA graphics card as well as the corresponding, disabled runtime power management. Thanks!